# Can we set window size in h2o automl for prediction of time series dataset?

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, stock, h2o.ai

I am trying to do stock price prediction with time series dataset using **h2o automl**. If I want to predict next 3 days closing price using previous 5 days  history, can I set this kind of window size in h2o automl?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, H2O AutoML (at least until now) does not implement time series forecasting algorithms (like ARIMA, Holt-Winters).